# Draw a rectangle with SimpleDocTemplate (ReportLab)

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I have used `SimpleDocTemplate` for making a table and now I want to draw a `rect` on this same page, but I don't know how to do.

I have tried this :

```
draw = Drawing(100, 1)
draw.add(Rect(0, 100, 500, 100))
```

But it don't works...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you code is not working is mostly likely because you are creating a `Drawing` of just 1 pixel high and 100 pixels wide. Which could never fit a `Rect` of 500 by 100 pixels.

So your code should be something like this:

```
draw = Drawing(500, 200)
draw.add(Rect(0, 100, 500, 100))
```